# change font-family Morris Donut Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, morris.js, donut-chart

I'm using the very lovely morris donut chart. thing is, I want to change font family for that chart text (inside donut) and cant manage to do it.
I will also want to add a 3% padding for inside text...

i tries to add

```
$("div svg text").attr("style", "font-family: 'Assistant' !important");
```

but  not working for me.

any one have an idea for me? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with `morris.js`, but since you're using jQuery, you can simply use the `.css()` method, instead of the changing the style attribute.

```
$('div svg text').css({
    "font-family" : "'Assistant' !important",
    "padding" : "3%"
});
```

You'll have to wrap the parameters inside an object to take effect.

Comment: Thanks Roberrrt for quick response!

Comment: I have tried to paste your script like so, but didnt manage to make it work:<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
/*
 * Play with this code and it'll update in the panel opposite.
 *
 * Why not try some of the options above?
 */
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: [
    {label: "עיצוב חווית משתמש", value: 35},
    {label: "פיתוח וכתיבת קוד", value: 50},
    {label: "קידום אורגני וממומן", value: 15}
  ]

});
$('div svg text').css({
    "font-family" : "'Assistant' !important",
    "padding" : "3%"
});

// ]]></script>

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function > Include jQuery

Answer (score 1):

I just have the same problem as you. I've find the text inside a Morris Donut Chart is use `<tspan>` as the last element and it doesn't specify any font-family. So if you only change the higher element but not last. `<tspan>` will overwrite your style. What you need to do is just basic css.

Add this to your css file.

```
tspan {
font-family: 'your desire font';
//you can add your extra style too :)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for change default font familly, you can set gridTextFamily property, default value is sans-serif

Comment: Can you show how you would do this in code and not just describe the answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).